# Canon 550D lens suggestions

Tags: lens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good two lens “starter kit”?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4316/what-is-a-good-two-lens-starter-kit)

I just need to ask one thing that I am confused that which lens to buy for my Canon 550D as I am not a PRO and I grooming myself in DSLR world so now I am going to make a trip to Mountain and Landscape areas and where I would love to shoot natural photography as well as portraits of my wife (majorly in daylight but surely night life would be considered as well but not majorly) so what would you guys recommend me under the budget of $300. I came up with these choices as I already used 50mm f/1.8 so I know from this portraits will be good but not the landscape pictures because capturing them wide is difficult I think. So please guys recommend me any good lens ?

Comment: -1 Sorry but I think this question has no definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lenshero.com is a good place to input your parameters and find suitable lenses. Just double check their results as sometimes there are little hiccups with the site, like the Amazon links don't always take you to the same lens.